# Cannot insert into database from php script I am using WAMP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into the MySQL database from a php script.I am using WAMP. When inserting data through phpmyadmin everything is ok and the data can also be displayed on the webpage but when trying to manually insert data thouth the php script nothing happens(I am doing this as a test my goal is to load data into server frOm Arduino). BElow is the code:

```
<?php

    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

    $temp="";
    $hum="";
    if(isset($_POST["temp1"])){ $temp = $_POST["temp1"];}
    if(isset($_POST["hum1"])){ $hum = $_POST["hum1"];}

    $safetemp1= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $temp);
    $safehum1= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $hum); 

    $query = "INSERT INTO tempLog (temperature, humidity) 
     VALUES (10, 10)";

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    if (!$result) {
       die("Nothing was inserted, something went wrong.");
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    header("Location: indexx.php")
```

Comment: I can't see how this could be failing. However, I'd check your HTML form and that to me, seems to be the most likely reason and code you're not showing. Yet, make sure those columns are int and not varchar. I also don't know why you're using POST arrays, but then using 10's as values. Checking for errors will determine that and you're not doing it. You also have a missing semi-colon for `header("Location: indexx.php")`

Comment: Is your PHP environment setup to display errors? Have you checked your error log?

Comment: When running the code the result is the line "Nothing was inserted, something is wrong".

Comment: Here... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`. Then tell us what they are.

Comment: Try printing out $query variable and execute it from phpMyAdmin. Will that work?

Comment: Fred-li.The colon was left when coping the code. THE problem is i do not know how to check errors.like i said this is just a test to see if data is being inserted.The POST array will be used for the data from Arduino

Comment: so.... what did my error codes above yield?

Comment: This is the result when i did as Fred -ii suggested:Duplicata du champ '0000-00-00 00:00:00' pour la clef 'PRIMARY

Comment: there you go, you have a constraint set for your column(s). Seeing someone posted an answer below, you can ask them. They're kind of like a shoe salesman, and stuck their foot in the door to make it an answer. Nothing new about what I already said though.

Comment: This is the result when i did as Fred -ii suggested:Duplicate field '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 1 for key primary;

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if there is an error, perhaps you misspelled a row or table name.

`echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));`

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$temp="";
$hum="";
if(isset($_POST["temp1"])){ $temp = $_POST["temp1"];}
if(isset($_POST["hum1"])){ $hum = $_POST["hum1"];}

$safetemp1= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $temp);
$safehum1= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $hum); 

$query = "INSERT INTO tempLog (temperature, humidity) 
 VALUES (10, 10)";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
if (!$result) {
   echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
   die("Nothing was inserted, something went wrong.");
}
mysqli_close($link);
header("Location: indexx.php")
```

Comment: error checking has already been said in comments. this is more like a foot in the door answer.

Comment: I know understand the problem.My first column is timestamp which records the real time the data is being inserted,so i dont know why is displaying only zeroes. Again it is Autoincrement so I thought it would not matter if I did not include it in the Query.P.S The timestamp is okay if data is from phpmyadmin

Comment: @MoloiMokete You can set the default for that field (using PhpMyAdmin) to "On update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" or you can pass the timestamp field a function to put the current time.  `INSERT INTO tempLog (timestamp, temperature, humidity) VALUES (NOW(), 10, 10)`.  I would recommend setting the default so you don't have to worry about passing `NOW()` every time.  You are correct about the auto increment field, no need to put that in the INSERT query.

Comment: @Lin Meyer I tried both solutions and they are working fine.Thanks everybody who took their time to help me.Next time cheeeeeers.